# Mongo db that does not exist but shows up in connection

Tags: mongodb, show, drop-database

I have dropped a MongoDB database called 'test' but when I connect to mongod it shows it in the connection. Please see the code below. Can you please help me understand what is going on? Is this a bug or I am missing something? Why is it that test is not in the list of databases when using show dbs command.
Thanks for the help.

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Me>c:\mongodb\bin\mongo

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8

connecting to: test

> db

test

> show dbs

local   0.078125GB

>

Comment: Your `show dbs` output only has one db, `local`, which is created automatically. If you don't specify a database on startup the `mongo` shell defaults to `test` which is why you see "connecting to: test". The database `test` will not be created until you start inserting data into a collection in it.

Comment: Why not make that an answer ? all is said.

Comment: That is a great explanation. I understand what is going on now. As a newbie to Mongo, I guess I have a lot to learn - Thanks Stennie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `show dbs` output only has one db, `local`, which is created automatically. If you don't specify a database on startup the `mongo` shell defaults to `test` which is why you see "connecting to: test". The database `test` will not be created until you start inserting data into a collection in it.